# Unable to Unzip Folder when invoked on a remote PC

Tags: powershell, extract, invoke, unzip, scriptblock

I'm Attempting to Unzip A folder located on a shared drive to the root of `C:\` on a remote PC but keep getting errors, how do i correct this Powershell?

```
$Computers = "LN-T48-PF11BL57"
Invoke-Command -Computername $Computers -ScriptBlock {
         Expand-Archive -LiteralPath '\\LNAPPS\APPS\Adobe iManage Fix\Program Files (x86).zip' -DestinationPath C:\ -Force } -Verbose

Write-Host "Enter to Exit"
```

This returns the following error:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '\\LNAPPS\APPS\Adobe iManage Fix\Program Files (x86).zip'.  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Expand-Archive], ParameterBindingException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Expand-Archive  
    + PSComputerName        : LN-T48-PF11BL57
```

Comment: Don't know why, but the error shows the command is 'eating' your first backslash of the UNC path. Have you tried not using `-LiteralPath` but instead use `-Path`? Otherwise, what happens if you use double quotes `"` around the path instead of single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:

1. Remember Windows balks are dropping stuff in the root c:.
2. So, are we to assume that \LNApps is a server name and \APPS is a
   folder share configured on that server?
3. Lastly, unless that server is running PowerShell v5, that
   Expand-Archive cmdlet is not there.

Hence this...

> : InvalidArgument: (:) [Expand-Archive], ParameterBindingException

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Caption
Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

$PSVersionTable


Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.19170
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2



Get-Command -Name '*Expand-archive*'

# No results



(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Caption

Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

$PSVersionTable


Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.316
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17763.316} 
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.316
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1




Get-Command -Name '*Expand-archive*'


CommandType     Name               Version    Source
-----------     ----               -------    ------
Function        Expand-Archive     1.0.1.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive
```

If that cmdlet is not there, you need to use the .Net namespace, [System.IO.Compression.FileSystem](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2015/06/09/pstip-compress-files-and-folders-with-system-io-compression-filesystem-class/), to deal with this use case.

> can be used to either compress or extract files using this class. The
>   following example will compress the files stored in the c:\testing
>   folder:

```
Add-Type -Assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory('c:\testing', 'c:\testing.zip','Optimal',$false)
```

> When you want to extract files, use the ExtractToDirectory method:

```
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('c:\testing.zip', 'c:\newtest')
```